# Make text box editable using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, textbox, readonly

I've a textbox with `readonly="readonly"` that means I can not edit it. But what I want is to make this textbox editable when user double clicks on it.

What I've tried yet is:

```
<input size="10" readonly="readonly" ondblclick="setEditable(this)"/>
```

and in JavaScript:

```
 function setEditable(i){
     i.readonly = false;
 }
```

But this does not worked. So ***how can I make a textbox editable, which is readonly, when user double clicks on it?***

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:**

To make it readonly again:

```
var el = document.getElementById('txt');
el.onblur = function(){
  this.setAttribute('readonly');
};
```

---

You can do this:

```
<input size="10" readonly="readonly" id="txt" />
```

**JS:**

```
var el = document.getElementById('txt');
el.ondblclick = function(){
  this.removeAttribute('readonly');
};
```

Comment: Thnx your answer works fine. I tried to accept your answer but it says "You can accept an answer in 5 minutes". So have to wait for 5 minutes. Also do you know answer for my **q2** which is related to `CSS`.

Comment: @Harry Joy: You should post your second question separately to get targeted answers :) I will check out then if i can answer or others may come up with answers :)

Comment: separated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016522/make-textbox-same-as-bachground

Answer (score 0):

as above pure javascript example by sarfraz try to make your javascript unobtrusive 
much better practice

Also as a lot of people do if you have jquery on page now you can use that to do same

In jquery

$('#txt').removeAttr("readonly");

Comment: thnx for reply but I use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

**To make text field editable**

```
document.getElementById("TextFieldId").readOnly=true;
```

**To make text field Uneditable**

```
document.getElementById("TextFieldId").readOnly=false;
```