# How to make a textbox indistinguishable from the background?

Tags: css, textbox

Which css should I apply to textbox that make it same as background means user does not feel like he is typing in textbox? I tried giving same background color but it still doesn't provide exact what I want. User still can feel that it's a textbox.

Comment: What do you mean by "user still can feel that its a textbox"? If you are about borders, then you can remove them using border-width:0px

Comment: Let me get this straight... you want to deliberately downgrade the user's experience by removing important visual clues?

Comment: @Ivan: You should post your comment as answer I will accept it cause you are the first who gave me solution about border.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
input {
    border: 0;
    background: transparent /* the important bit */
}
```

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/eUmr2/) (I added a blue border on a parent element so you can see where the `<input>` is)
http://jsfiddle.net/eUmr2/1/ (with gradient background to more easily see the `transparent`)

---

Appears to work in IE6:

[image]

Comment: Just a side note, background: transparent is only IE7+ & partial IE6 (if that matters)

Comment: @True North Creative: I tested (see image), and in this case it appears to work in IE6.

Comment: Yeah, your solution is right.  Just wanted to point the IE snaffu out. Link for reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx#color

Comment: thanks for the indirect link to Geotek netrenderer, that thing is FAST!

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: Yup, much faster than booting my IE6 virtual machine when all I need it a quick screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you should first of all "hide" borders of textarea or input field. You can simply use "border:none;" property for this. In this case, if both backgrounds will be the same (e.g. textarea and rest of the container) it will be displayed like you need.

I don't know exactly what are you trying to achieve, but this method is used usually for not standard designs of form fields. The only you need to do is to be sure that this part of your page is OK from usability point of view.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the borders and apply the same background color as the container it's in.