# enable multiple checkboxes when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, checkbox

I have 5 text boxes whose IDs and names are all different from each other.  But i have to enable all 5 text boxes when a certain checkbox is checked.  How do i do this with JavaScript?

Comment: may be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016326/make-text-box-editable-using-javascript) can help you.

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery you can do

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox" value=""><br>
<input type="text" value="" disabled="disabled"><br>
<input type="text" value="" disabled="disabled"><br>
<input type="text" value="" disabled="disabled"><br>

var $input = $('input[type="text"]');
$('#check').live('click', function() {
    $(this).is(':checked') ? $input.removeAttr('disabled') : $input.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/CpmkE/3/