# Textboxes to show and edit data

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have text boxes that have the border removed so they don't appear as text boxes and are read only.  I also have an edit button that shows the border and allows a user to edit the information and save it to a database.

My question should I be displaying data in a text box?  It just makes it easier to edit otherwise I would have to add the text box dynamically when the edit button is clicked.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016326/make-text-box-editable-using-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is a 'span' or 'div' with the html5 attrtibute 'contenteditable' set to true;

```
<div contenteditable="true"/>
```

You can toggle true/false on click button event.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I would like to use textboxes so I can have a group of textboxes get saved at the same time by running an ajax call and using $("form").serialize()

Comment: I see. It's a matter of choice. I like 'contenteditable', and if you like to use it you could do something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83q8p/).

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a div tag and load your output there.

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

It would remain invisible until used, and it would not be editable, and of course you could mark it up any way you like if you want the output area to stand out later.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this with jquery-

Html :

```
<input type="text" id="data" disabled="true" value="sampel data"/>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Edit" />
```

Jquery:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $("#data").attr("disabled", false);
});
```

[Live Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/sharif084/5dup5/)